# Alternative software to Freedom and/or Anti-Social?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

Freedom:
http://macfreedom.com/

Anti-Social:
http://anti-social.cc/

Simply put: Where can I find an alternative software to either-or/both these apps?

Note: Part of the appeal of these apps is allowing the user to explicitly make it extra difficult to re-enable these services. Unplugging the network cable might seem to achieve the same results from an glance, but the added difficulty in re-enabling those services is what makes these apps valuable.

Comment: Turning off the wifi or unplugging the Ethernet is a great cross platform alternative :P

Comment: Added note. The value in these apps is not in the disconnection, but rather in the added difficulty in re-enabling them.

Comment: SelfControl -- The Linux port ? "Linux port of the Mac OS X application. Uses Perl/Gtk2 + iptables. Provides basic timed blocking of specified hosts."

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge internet social-media`

Comment: what's difficult about re-enabling it?

Comment: @Stefano: That's exactly the point. The user of these apps desire is to make is unreasonably difficult to re-enable the service, hence forcing them to work without the distraction of having an Internet connection.

Comment: @mummey I understand, what I meant was, how exactly is it difficult to re-enable? (Because I bet I could hack something like that together in no time)

Comment: Ah, if the user wants to re-enable before the stated time is up, he/she has to restart their computer.

Comment: but in ubuntu the shutdown takes only 2-3 sec at max and 20-30 sec in starting that it will in any case be a matter of around 35 sec before you browse the internet.also if you are using a ssd you could restart within 12 seconds.

Comment: Well let's say you are working on something..and you get email pop-up or a facebook notification from gwibber, they can be distracting...you would want to read it and reply thereby disturbing the work progress. In that sense, making the user shutdown and then restart to access the internet would definitely stop that behavior.

Comment: We're all [pigeons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._F._Skinner) :P

Comment: @Nik: Exactly! Not to mention a restart has the added cost of having to close and reopen your applications in-use.

Comment: Your problem is self-control, rather than a technical one.  You can try and install stuff which raises the difficulty of straying off-task, but you will never make it impossible, so you will always succumb.  Work on your self-discipline instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Self Control](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl.html)**  ([Download Link](http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl/selfcontrol_0.9-1_all.deb))

From an [OMG!Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/self-control-ubuntu/)

> Self Control allows you to ‘block access to incoming and/or outgoing mail servers and websites’ for a specified amount of time.

[image: Self Control Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Firstly make sure you only have one web browser (i.e Firefox) and then Install [Leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) addon

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do can be undone if the user your trying to target has sudo rights (administrative access). So your first priority is to make sure you secure your machines in such a way as to prevent sudo access.

Once you have this set up correctly, you can move to installing packages that control access via time based rules.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a chromium extension named "StayFocused" doing that. nice extension if you're just using chromium.